# Opening Tab Next to Active Tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

For my Chrome extension, I need to open a new tab next to the active/current tab. But `tab.create` method always append the tab at the end of tab list.

Firefox has `relatedToCurrent` property to set tab position.

Is there any Chrome equivalent for opening tabs next to active tab?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the "index" property to specify the position at calling chrome.tabs.create() function. If you want to open a new tab next to the current tab:

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true, currentWindow: true
  }, tabs => {
    let index = tabs[0].index;
    chrome.tabs.create({
      ...,
      index: index + 1,
      ...
    }, tab => {
      ...
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: `chrome.tabs.getCurrent` doesn't return the currently active tab. You should use `chrome.tabs.query({active:true}, ...)`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just edited the code above. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I got `Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode` because of let. So I replaced `let` with `var`. Hope it is OK this way.

Comment: Gotta filter by `activeWindow: true` as well.

Comment: @Xan did you mean currentWindow? And why the filter is necessary. I do not get.

Comment: Yes, sorry, `currentWindow`. Otherwise the first tab in the results array may belong to another window (being active in it).

Comment: @Xan thanks. Does currentWindow filter make sure the tab will open in the focused window? This code works in background.js. BTW, does background.js is attached to any window or live in its own scope without any window connection?

Comment: `tabs.create` defaults to current window. I'm not sure about background-window connection, but it is unique, I suppose it's not attached - at the very least, it does not have a tabId.

Comment: @Xan thanks again. Say there are 4 browser windows. Which one will be picked to open tab by the code for `currenWindow:true` case? Is it last focused window?

Comment: @JohnSewell https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#current-window Read "event page = background page"

Comment: @Xan thanks, it seems I am using background page. So I may not use event page for my case. That documentation page says current window may not be topmost or focused window. Do you have any other suggestion that will make tab opening in last active focused window?

Comment: You really worry too much. You are using a background page. Therefore, `currentWindow` there is the last focused window if it exists (in rare circumstances, an extension can continue executing after all windows close). If you don't indicate anything to `chrome.tabs.create`, it will default to current window in that sense.

Comment: @Xan thanks again. Got confused because of the sentence that says `"It's important to realize that this can be different from the topmost or focused window."` in that documentation page. After some tests, as you said, currentWindow points to the last focused window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create new tab from injected content script in a tab next to it then below is the code for content script and background/servicer worker script.

```
//content script code
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ open_new_tab: true, url: 'https://www.google.com' })

//background.js or service_worker.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    
    if (request.open_new_tab) {
        //sender is the tab the above content script code is injected in
        chrome.tabs.create({url: request.url, index: sender.tab.index + 1})
    }
    
    //if you are using Manifest V3 then always call sendResponse as below
    sendResponse(true)
    
})
```